# how to use CX_freeze with python3.8

Tags: python, python-3.8

Dears

I installed Cx_freeze on python3.8 after many trials and when i started to build my program using

**python setup.py bdist_wininst**
 and run the built file,get the below errors
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVaJL.png)

my setup file is

```
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
    import os.path

    PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
    # Dependencies are automatically detected, but some modules need help.
    buildOptions = dict(
        packages = [ 'tkinter','os','collections','xml.DOM','pandas','PIL' ,'setuptools'],
        excludes =['adodbapi', 'asyncio', 'atomicwrites', 'attr', 'babel', 'backcall', 'backports', 'bokeh', 'bottleneck', 'bs4', 'certifi', 'cffi', 'chardet', 'click', 'cloudpickle',  'colorama', 'concurrent', 'cryptography',  'curses', 'Cython', 'cytoolz', 'dask', 'dbm', 'defusedxml', 'distributed', 'docutils', 'et_xmlfile', 'future', 'h5py', 'html', 'idna', 'importlib_metadata', 'ipykernel', 'IPython', 'ipython_genutils', 'ipywidgets', 'jedi', 'jinja2', 'joblib', 'jsonschema', 'jupyter_client', 'jupyter_core', 'lib2to3', 'llvmlite', 'locket', 'lxml', 'markupsafe', 'mkl_fft', 'mkl_random', 'mock', 'more_itertools', 'msgpack', 'multiprocessing', 'nbconvert', 'nbformat', 'nose', 'notebook', 'numba', 'numexpr', 'numpydoc', 'olefile', 'openpyxl', 'OpenSSL', 'packaging', 'parso', 'partd', 'pathlib2', 'patsy',  'pkg_resources', 'pluggy', 'prometheus_client', 'prompt_toolkit', 'psutil', 'py', 'pycparser', 'pydoc_data', 'pygments', 'PyQt5', 'pyreadline', 'pyrsistent', 'pywin', 'pyximport', 'qtpy', 'requests', 'scipy', 'send2trash',  'sklearn', 'sortedcontainers', 'soupsieve', 'sphinx', 'sqlalchemy', 'sqlite3', 'statsmodels', 'tables', 'tblib', 'terminado', 'test', 'testpath', 'toolz', 'tornado', 'traitlets',  'wcwidth', 'win32com', 'winpty', 'win_unicode_console', 'wsgiref', 'xlrd', 'xlsxwriter', 'xlwt',  'xmlrpc', 'yaml', 'zict', 'zmq', '_pytest'] ,#['adodbapi', 'asyncio', 'atomicwrites', 'attr', 'babel', 'backcall', 'backports', 'bokeh', 'bottleneck', 'bs4', 'certifi',  'cffi', 'chardet', 'click', 'cloudpickle', 'colorama', 'concurrent', 'cryptography','ctypes', 'curses', 'Cython', 'cytoolz', 'dask', 'dbm', 'defusedxml', 'distributed', 'docutils', 'et_xmlfile', 'future', 'h5py', 'html', 'importlib_metadata', 'ipywidgets', 'jedi', 'jinja2', 'joblib', 'jupyter_client', 'jupyter_core', 'lib2to3', 'llvmlite', 'locket', 'lxml', 'markupsafe', 'mkl_fft', 'mkl_random', 'mock', 'more_itertools', 'msgpack', 'multiprocessing', 'nbconvert', 'nbformat', 'nose', 'notebook', 'numba', 'numexpr', 'numpydoc', 'olefile', 'openpyxl', 'OpenSSL', 'packaging',  'parso', 'partd', 'pathlib2', 'patsy', 'pkg_resources', 'pluggy', 'prometheus_client', 'prompt_toolkit', 'psutil', 'py', 'pycparser', 'pydoc_data', 'pygments', 'PyQt5', 'pyreadline', 'pyrsistent','pywin', 'pyximport', 'qtpy', 'requests', 'scipy', 'send2trash', 'setuptools', 'sklearn', 'sortedcontainers', 'soupsieve', 'sphinx', 'sqlalchemy', 'statsmodels', 'tables', 'tblib', 'terminado', 'test', 'testpath', 'tornado', 'traitlets',  'wcwidth', 'sqlite3', 'wsgiref', 'xlrd', 'xlsxwriter', 'xlwt', 'xmlrpc', 'yaml', 'zict', 'zmq'],

        include_files = [os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
             os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
             'Photos/']
    )


    setup(
        name='ET_Viewer',
        version = 'S_Malt_1.0',
        description = 'XML parsing program',
        options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
        executables =  [Executable('ET_Viewer.py',
                                   targetName='SMETXMLV.exe',
                                   copyright='Copyright(C) 2019',
                                   base='Win32GUI',
                                   icon= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),'Photos/icon.ico'))]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add numpy to the build_exe packages